# How can I add Swipe Gesture to AVPlayer in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, gesture

I am using Swift 3 and I want to add swipe gesture to `AVPlayer`. Somebody told me that in order to do this I have to use another view and bring that view to the top of the video - So I did it, and here is my code: (**But didn't work**) :(

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIAlertViewDelegate {

let myFirstButton = UIButton()
let mySecondButton = UIButton()
var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var Player = AVPlayer()
var swipeGesture = UIGestureRecognizer()
var sView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    ////////////
    sView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(sView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sView)


    //////Swipe Gesture

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeCustom = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeCustom.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.init(rawValue: 200)
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeCustom)


    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)


    //////////////////////End Swipe Gesture

    let currentPlayerItem = Player.currentItem
    let duration = currentPlayerItem?.asset.duration
    let currentTime = Float(self.Player.currentTime().value)


        if currentTime >= 5 {

            print("OK")

        }else if currentTime <= 5 {

            print("NO")
        }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
        }
    })



    /////////////
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5.0) {
                // check if player is still playing
                if self.Player.rate != 0 {
                    print("OK")
                    print("Player reached 5 seconds")
                }
            }
        }
    })

}


fileprivate var firstAppear = true
//////Swipe Gesture 
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            print("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("Swiped left")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
            print("Swiped up")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.init(rawValue: 200):
            print("Swiped Custom")

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}    
/////////End Swipe Gesture
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    if firstAppear {
        do {
            try playBackgroundMovieVideo()
            firstAppear = false
        } catch AppError.invalidResource(let NMNF6327, let m4v) {
            debugPrint("Could not find resource \(NMNF6327).\(m4v)")
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Generic error")
        }


    }
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
}
fileprivate func playBackgroundMovieVideo() throws {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NMNF6327", ofType:"m4v") else {
        throw AppError.invalidResource("NMNF6327", "m4v")

    }

    self.Player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    playerController.player = self.Player
    playerController.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = false



    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 70, height: 50)
    self.myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.myFirstButtonpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)

    playerController.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)

    mySecondButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Options.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    mySecondButton.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 5, width: 70, height: 50)
    self.mySecondButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.mySecondButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(mySecondButton)

    playerController.view.addSubview(mySecondButton)


    self.present(playerController, animated: false) {
        self.Player.play()
    }
}

func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    self.Player.play()
}

func myFirstButtonpressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    let alertView = UIAlertView();
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "Continue");
    alertView.delegate=self;
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "restart");
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "Middle");
    alertView.title = "PAUSE";
    alertView.message = "";
    alertView.show();

    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.present(playerController , animated: true)
    self.Player.pause()

}

func mySecondButtonClicked(){

}





func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int) {


    if buttonIndex == 0
{

    self.Player.play()
    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    print("Continue")


}

    else if buttonIndex == 1 {
    self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
     self.Player.play()
     myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)


    }
    ////Middle
else if buttonIndex == 2 {
    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    let timeScale = self.Player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale;
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( +9 , timeScale!)
    self.Player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
    self.Player.play()
    }

}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
    return false
}
func update() {
    myFirstButton.isHidden=false
}

}


enum AppError : Error {
case invalidResource(String, String)
    }
```

Comment: these are all of my codes and I have tested these code in another project and their working well

Comment: Have you added `sView` as a subview?

Comment: yes as you see in the codes I brought this to the top with self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sView)

Comment: I added sview as sub view too but didn't get the answer too here is that method         self.view.addSubview(sView)

Comment: what about using [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller)?

Comment: No i want to Just using Swipe Gesture

Comment: One possibility is that sView might have __isUserInteractionEnabled__ set to false, be too small or not visible on the screen. Using "View UI Hierarchy" tool or painting sView to some unusual color might help figuring it out. In particular, I think, UIView() initialization makes a UIView with CGRect.zero for a frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two mistakes on your code.**

**1. Adding gesture view on wrong controller's view.**  Instead of adding gesture view to AVPlayerViewController() you were adding on initial controller, which will get covered by AVPlayerViewController() after presenting.

**3. Wrong selector's target** You were making false assumption about **target** on `let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: sView, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))` . You were setting target to sView and implementing selector method on ViewController.

Here target means the target object for selector method. So Changing target to self (i.e. your view controller) will make your view controller a target for selector method `func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)`

**please refer the following corrected code.**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIAlertViewDelegate {

let myFirstButton = UIButton()
let mySecondButton = UIButton()
var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var Player = AVPlayer()
var swipeGesture = UIGestureRecognizer()
var sView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeCustom = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeCustom.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.init(rawValue: 200)
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeCustom)


    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
    self.sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)


    //////////////////////End Swipe Gesture

    let currentPlayerItem = Player.currentItem
    let duration = currentPlayerItem?.asset.duration
    let currentTime = Float(self.Player.currentTime().value)


    if currentTime >= 5 {

        print("OK")

    }else if currentTime <= 5 {

        print("NO")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
        }
    })



    /////////////
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5.0) {
                // check if player is still playing
                if self.Player.rate != 0 {
                    print("OK")
                    print("Player reached 5 seconds")
                }
            }
        }
    })

}


fileprivate var firstAppear = true
//////Swipe Gesture
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            print("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("Swiped left")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
            print("Swiped up")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.init(rawValue: 200):
            print("Swiped Custom")

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
/////////End Swipe Gesture
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    if firstAppear {
        do {
            try playBackgroundMovieVideo()
            firstAppear = false
        } catch AppError.invalidResource(let NMNF6327, let m4v) {
            debugPrint("Could not find resource \(NMNF6327).\(m4v)")
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Generic error")
        }


    }
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
}
fileprivate func playBackgroundMovieVideo() throws {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NMNF6327", ofType:"m4v") else {
        throw AppError.invalidResource("NMNF6327", "m4v")

    }

    self.Player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    playerController.player = self.Player
    playerController.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = false



    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 70, height: 50)
    self.myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.myFirstButtonpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)


    mySecondButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Options.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    mySecondButton.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 5, width: 70, height: 50)
    self.mySecondButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.mySecondButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(mySecondButton)


    sView.frame = self.view.frame
    playerController.view.addSubview(sView)
    playerController.view.bringSubview(toFront: sView)

    // ****** buttons are added after sview ********** 
    playerController.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)

    playerController.view.addSubview(mySecondButton)

    self.present(playerController, animated: false) {
        self.Player.play()
    }
}

func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    self.Player.play()
}

func myFirstButtonpressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    let alertView = UIAlertView();
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "Continue");
    alertView.delegate=self;
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "restart");
    alertView.addButton(withTitle: "Middle");
    alertView.title = "PAUSE";
    alertView.message = "";
    alertView.show();

    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.present(playerController , animated: true)
    self.Player.pause()

}

func mySecondButtonClicked(){

}





func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int) {


    if buttonIndex == 0
    {

        self.Player.play()
        myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        print("Continue")


    }

    else if buttonIndex == 1 {
        self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.Player.play()
        //myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)


    }
        ////Middle
    else if buttonIndex == 2 {
       myFirstButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        let timeScale = self.Player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale;
        let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( +9 , timeScale!)
        self.Player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
        self.Player.play()
    }

}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
    return false
}
func update() {
    myFirstButton.isHidden=false
}

 }


enum AppError : Error {
case invalidResource(String, String)
}
```

Comment: its worked But I can't use buttons ! can I add them to sview?

Comment: add buttons only after sview is added ! See updated code

Comment: please Vote My Question

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

You can do it without sView, just add a gesture recognizer to AVPlayerViewController's view:

```
func playVideo() {
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath))
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    playerController.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    present(playerController, animated: false) {
        playerController.player?.play()
    }
}

@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("swipe up")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped ! Unfortunately on newer iOS (starting from 11 I think), swiping leads to moving the video in the controller, and seems to take priority over the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. Do you know of any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to initialize your sView properly. Make sure you assigned needed frame to sView and added it to self.view as a subview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(sView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sView)

    // add you gestures to sView here ...
}
```

Comment: didn't worked please help me to get the Reputation for Gift

Comment: I can't understand what is a problem. Created sample project with AVPlayer and gestures that are working [here](https://github.com/tomagh/stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/stackoverflow-44288116)

Comment: I checked your codes in GitHub but still didn't work for me please help me to get 50 reputation

Comment: Well, the only thing I can do in your case is debug your code sample, if you share it with stackoverflow community.

Comment: ok wait please this night I will put all of the codes here (Edit Question)

Comment: I have Edited codes now you can see all of my codes here please help me to get 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:`playerController.view.addSubview(self.sView)` instead of `self.view.addSubview(sView)`

And you should add self as tagart just like this:
`let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))`

It will work . This is my console:https://i.stack.imgur.com/agaBx.jpg