# Disable swipe to close on AVPlayerController

Tags: swift, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

iOS 11 has introduced a swipe to close AVPlayerController. I have app that is aimed at toddlers so the screen is easily swiped causing the video to close. Is there anyway to remove the gesture to close the player?

I have tried adding a gesture override to the AVPlayerController's view but it doesn't work. There is a possible solution on [How can I add Swipe Gesture to AVPlayer in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288116/how-can-i-add-swipe-gesture-to-avplayer-in-swift-3) but there must be a cleaner way

Comment: You shouldn't use AVPlayerController, you have to write your own implementation of Video Player with AVPlayer.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use AVPlayerController? We use alot of the baked in features of it so not feasible to write our own implementation at the moment

Comment: Let me know if you find the solution. I am also finding the way to disable swipe to close

Comment: I managed to fix it.  Just added an answer to explain. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve issue. As @Vakas commented, the AVPlayerController shouldn't be subclassed. I had originally subclassed it and presented using a modal segue. This was causing the problem.

To solve it, I created another view controller that embeds the AVPlayerController in it.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

    var videoRecord: Video!
    var presentingController = ""
    var videos = [Video]()
    var presentingPlaylist:  Playlist?

    let playerViewController = TFLPlayerController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerViewController.delegate = self

        playerViewController.videoRecord = videoRecord
        playerViewController.videos = self.videos
        playerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = false

        // Add the original AVPlayerController in here
        self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)

        let playerView = playerViewController.view
        playerView?.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.view.addSubview(playerView!)
        playerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

}
```

I basically use this View Controller to pass through the properties such as videos, etc, to the originally subclassed AVPlayerController.

Answer (score 2):

If AVPlayerController is embedded (not presenting) the Close button is not presented in the controls view.

My solution is to find the subview with gesture recognizers and remove pan gesture recognizer

```
for v in playerViewController.view.subviews {
     if v.gestureRecognizers != nil {
         for gr in v.gestureRecognizers! {
             if gr is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
                // remove pan gesture to prevent closing on pan
                v.removeGestureRecognizer(gr)
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: it finds and removes the gr but panning keeps working

Answer (score 0):

None of the comments above solved the issue (iOS 13+). Solution:

```
let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
avPlayerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
```

where handlePanGesture(_:) is the method that will be called if a pan happen on the screen (and the video won't move - that was the problem in the question that it was dragged), and avPlayerViewController is the AVPlayerViewController instance.

Note: if you want to prevent the pinch / rotation and any other gesture, you can add for every gesture a new UI...GestureRecognizer. Just make sure, that all UI...GestureRecognizers' delegate is set, and this function is implemented:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```