# How to make custom video player with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a video player like youtube, with double-tap the screen to fast forward 5 seconds. But I'm having trouble implementing that. I tried using code below:

```
class VideoViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.delegate = self

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


extension VideoViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("doubletapped")
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: self.fileURLs[indexPath.row])
        let playerController = VideoViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
            playerController.player!.play()
        }
```

But still Swift cannot recognize the double tap when playing video. I try to disable userinteractoin but still no luck. Anyone please give me some hints.
Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add Swipe Gesture to AVPlayer in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288116/how-can-i-add-swipe-gesture-to-avplayer-in-swift-3)

Comment: @Renuka Pandey, Nah I tried that but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make user interaction enable
View.isUserInteractionEnable =true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).